# ABP Update for Projects in Inner Folders

Tags: c#, .net-core, abp

I tried updating ABP via cli from version 4.2 to the latest 4.4 using

> abp update

The folder structure is something similar to the one from the sample Microservice Template https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Samples/Microservice-Demo

host
--X.HttpApi.Host
----X.HttpApi.Host.csproj
modules
--product
----src
------ProductManagement.Application
--------ProductManagement.Application.csproj

What happened is the projects in "host" folder is updated but not the projects in the "modules" folder. Can't seem to find other options that can achieve it from the cli docs.
How can I update projects in inner folders like "modules" without having to do it individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `abp update` command in the directory of your project.

> You can use the update command both in **.sln** and **.csproj** directories. (You can update version of packages both solution-based and project/class-library-based)

Open the path of your **ProductManagement.Application.csproj** project in your terminal and run the `abp update` command. Then your project should be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, but it's really a tedious job to do individually for each project folder. Based on ABP templates, the src and test folder already has 10 projects or so for just 1 module. Hence, I'm wondering if there is a more seamless solution to this.

Comment: Did you try the `abp update` command in the directory of the modules folder?

Comment: I couldn't wait any longer so I've already updated by each projects individually. Will try out modules folder the next round, it does reduce the number of times I need to run the update in comparison to each project. I was hoping there is a way that it can be done from the root/solution folder itself. Thanks anyway.